# python simple_salesforce proxy usage

Tags: python, proxy, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm using python simple_salesforce module from this example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce. Specifically:

`proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128"
}`

`from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='myemail@example.com.sandbox', password='password', security_token='token', sandbox=True, proxies=proxies)`

Its failing with the below error.

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))`

If I dont use proxy, it works fine. My requirement is to enable proxy. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: A) Can you use the proxy just fine with your web browser? B) I'm assuming you are running squid based on the port number, can you post your squid configuration?  Perhaps squid is blocking SSL/TLS?

Comment: I'm also assuming that, but we have a proxy server configured as the server for outgoing requests and I run this program on is behind firewall. When I use `>>> sf = Salesforce(instance='na1.salesforce.com', session_id='', proxies=proxies)
>>> sf
<simple_salesforce.api.Salesforce object at 0x26f5190>
` it seems to be working, but when I add user password etc, it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to the beginning of the program will solve this problem. 
I was using urllib2 in python and that takes care of forwarding the request through proxy.
For the answer to my question:

If your hostname and port for proxy are xyz1-pqr01.abc.company.com and 3128 then

`import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://xyz1-pqr01.abc.company.com:3128'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://xyz1-pqr01.abc.company.com:3128'`